# Filter out $0.00 values on Google Play order history

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-play, tampermonkey

I wanted to check an old purchase on Google Play, but the [history](https://play.google.com/store/account/orderhistory) will show everything that I claimed. Including, a ton of free apps (listed as $0.00), and it's impossible to filter anything in that list.

So I thought I could make a simple TamperMonkey script to do it for me, but it's not working for some reason.
What am I missing here? Thanks.

Here's what I got so far:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Filter Out $0.00 Garbage
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  ...
// @author       Me
// @match        https://play.google.com/store/account/orderhistory
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=google.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('mshXob');
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; ++i) {
    var item = ele[i];
    if (item.innerHTML == '$0.00') {
      var gp = item.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
      gp.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: consider using the .filter() method on arrays. You pass a predicate function. If the function returns true, then it's included in the new array, if not, the item is filtered out. `ele.filter(el=>el.innerHTML=='$0.00')`

Comment: @BrandonPiña I'm not sure how to use this exactly, but as I understood, it will remove the element itself? If so, that's not what I'm after. I'm trying to remove the entire row which is a grand-grandparent div basically. Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: @root Just following up - did the below answer work for you? Did you get a chance to test it? I'm wondering if it works reliably or if the DOM structure is not reliable? If it doesn't work for you please let me know what happens and lets see if we can tweak it. Otherwise, if you wouldn't mind giving it the nod, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try it out with XPATH

Here:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Filter Out $0.00 Garbage
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  ...
// @author       Me
// @match        https://play.google.com/store/account/orderhistory*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=google.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    const MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
    const observer = new MutationObserver(hideZeroElements);
    // tried with div elements but does not seem to work.
    observer.observe(document.body, {
        subtree: true,
        childList: true,
        attributes: false
    });
})();

function hideZeroElements(mutations, observer) {
  /**
  * Get all the divs whom grand children contain a 0,00 value or 0.00 in your case
  */
  const history = document.evaluate('//div[div[2]/div//div[contains(text(), "0.00")]]', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  /**
  * Loop over all the elements found and hide them.
  */
  for ( let i = 0; i < history.snapshotLength; i++) {
      history.snapshotItem(i).style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

**Note**: I'm not sure if there is a way to disconnect the observer or not inside the userscript.

Comment: All scripts are not working on FF for some reason. I tested yours on Edge, and although it worked, only for the first page of orders. After other pages get automatically loaded, the script no longer works *(same goes for my original script and @cssyphus)*.

Comment: I have updated my answer can you try it again, I have added an mutation observer to check for DOM changes and changed xpath for 0.00 elements, hope it works in FF.

Comment: Well, it seems to have hid everything. Even the none 0.00 divs for some reason.

Comment: Tried it on FF 101.0.1 (64-bits) and it is working, maybe it's because my Google Play account is in Spanish and shows different DOM structure not sure. Still it does not make any sense why it would remove all the non 0.00 values.

Comment: Can you give us some more information? Like console logs or anything else that might have caused this unexpected error.

Comment: No scripts work on FF (on Google Play Purchase History) for some reason. As I mentioned to @cssyphus, even a simple alert('test'); doesn't even work on that specific page using FF. And in the console, I see this: *Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).*

Comment: I did manage to get it to work on Edge (Chromium) though. I used the first half of your script (MutationObserver) but used my original script inside the "hideZeroElements" function. I didn't think it would work, but it did!

Comment: What version of tampermonkey are you using on FF?

Answer (score 1):

You may be relying on classNames that change. JavaScript libraries like Angular/React/etc may change IDs and ClassNames to obfuscate code.

Try using DOM selectors and DOM traversal methods that do not rely on constant ID and class names.

Try this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         play.google.com/store/account/orderhistory
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @match        https://play.google.com/store/account/orderhistory
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    const container = document.querySelector('body>c-wiz:nth-child(5)>div>div>div:nth-child(3)+div>div:nth-child(1)');
    const orders = container.querySelectorAll('div');
    orders.forEach((el,_) => {
        const bucks = el.querySelector('div:nth-child(2)>div>div:nth-child(2)');
        if (bucks !== null){
            if (bucks.innerText === 'US$0.00') el.remove();
        }
    });

})();
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but it's not working. It doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer responding to your comment *(could not respond with a comment because more flexibility required)*.

Does the TM icon get a red dot when you visit that page? If so, the script is running but not working; if not, the @match line is not triggering the script (i.e. does not match the url). Can you determine which is the case?

Next thing to check: open DevTools (F12) and paste in the first querySelector. Does DevTools show anything like this *(DevTools is responding with `div.NgfTBf.fny74c`)*:

[image]

If nothing appears when you paste-in that querySelector line, it might be necessary to tweak that selector. The way to do that is to build-up the selector bit-by-bit and see what happens as each stage is added:

```
document.querySelector('body')  //this HAS to return something...!
```

[image]

then:

```
document.querySelector('body>c-wiz:nth-child(5)')
```

(that one might need to be `nth-child(3)` - try that also)

At each stage, Chrome DevTools should show something. For example:

[image]

You might find this video to be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SowaJlX1uKA

Let me know what you see.

Comment: I can see the script is running (little red icon).  
I ran the first QuerySelector and I did get a result:

`<div class="NgfTBf fny74c" jsname="cC57zf" jscontroller="Zt7Hhf" jsaction="UZBd6c:ebQRw">`  

That being said, I noticed an error message in the DevTool:  
*"Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”)."*  

So maybe this not an issue with the script itself?

Comment: As a test, I tried to use a script containing only `alert('test');` and it didn't work. But it did work on other websites, so I'm guessing it's some sort of security related issue.

Comment: That is somewhat odd because it does work for me. What browser are you using? *I tested this on the [Brave browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_(web_browser)) started by [Brendan Eich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Eich).* Neverfear, we'll get to the bottom of this ... !

Comment: Oh, I'm using Firefox 101.0.1 (64-bit), so perhaps it's specific to FF. I'll try to test it on a different browser.

Comment: I just tested it on Edge (Chromium) and my original script, yours, as well as the one by @arslan-sohail-bano all worked, kind of.  
All three scripts worked only for the first page, after that they all stopped working. Google seems to be lazy-loading orders history (I have A LOT).